# Updgrading MQ to SHA2 support

Tags: weblogic, ibm-mq, mq, sha2

I have a current requirement for upgrading MQ to support SHA2 . Currently we are using MQ6 , will upgrade to MQ7  to enable SHA2 support.We are using Weblogic8 for our current MQ6. Why do we have to upgrade our weblogic server for newer MQ7 upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

If you're making the effort to upgrade from such an old unsupported release of MQ, why would you only go to MQ 7.0 which itself is out of support?

Why not consider in support options such as 7.1, 7.5, 8.0, or 9.0 and benefit from years of new function, bug fixes, and other improvements?

You won't find anything as old as Weblogic 8 on an MQ 7+ supported environment statement as it is itself very old and presumably no longer supported.